# How to create dynamic column using react-data-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a LogsData in my react App:

```
 const dailyLogsData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      date_created: "01/15/2023",
      time_updated: "15:53:05",
      usage_notes: "sample notes",
      maintenance_notes: "sample notes",

      devices: [
        { device_name: "Port Engine", device_value: "0125", device_id: 1 },
        { device_name: "Generator", device_value: "0252", device_id: 2 },
        { device_name: "Water Maker", device_value: "0321", device_id: 3 },
        { device_name: "Fuel Engine", device_value: "", device_id: 4 },
        { device_name: "Radiator", device_value: "", device_id: 5 },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      date_created: "01/16/2023",
      time_updated: "15:53:05",
      usage_notes: "sample notes",
      maintenance_notes: "sample notes",

      devices: [
        { device_name: "Port Engine", device_value: "0125", device_id: 1 },
        { device_name: "Generator", device_value: "0252", device_id: 2 },
        { device_name: "Water Maker", device_value: "0321", device_id: 3 },
        { device_name: "Fuel Engine", device_value: "0321", device_id: 4 },
        { device_name: "Radiator", device_value: "0321", device_id: 5 },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

And I want to display each device name in a column and the device value should be in the row.

I have a simple solution, but I do not know how to get the device value for each device

```
const columns = dailyLogsData[0].devices.map((item) => ({
    key: item.device_name.replace(/ /g, ""),
    name: item.device_name.toUpperCase(),
  }));

  const columns2 = [
    { key: "id", name: "ID" },
    { key: "date_time", name: "DATE/TIME" },
    { key: "usage_notes", name: "USAGE NOTES" },
    { key: "maintenance_notes", name: "MAINTENANCE NOTES" },
    ...columns,
  ];

 const rows = dailyLogsData.map((item) => ({
    id: item.id,
    date_time: `${item.date_created} | ${item.time_updated}`,
    usage_notes: item.usage_notes,
    maintenance_notes: item.maintenance_notes,
  }));

return(
  <DataGrid columns={columns2} rows={rows} />
)
```

Here is the output so far:

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4YdH.png)

I am using this NPM Package for additional info: [react-data-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-grid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a multiple map function as below here:

```js
const rows = dailyLogsData.map((item) => {
  const row = {
    id: item.id,
    date_time: `${item.date_created} | ${item.time_updated}`,
    usage_notes: item.usage_notes,
    maintenance_notes: item.maintenance_notes,
  };

  item.devices.forEach((device) => {
    row[device.device_name.replace(/ /g, "")] = device.device_value;
  });

  return row;
});
``
```